# Make a function that autodetects when unique

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, vector, 2d-vector

I need to have a function in c++ that gets an element from a vector of strings as soon as the input is unique.

For example, my vector contains `{"DELETE", "HELP", "GO FORWARD", "GO BACKWARDS"}`.

If my input is then `"H"`, the function should output `"HELP"` If the input is `"H 55"`, it should ignore the 55 and still output `"HELP"`.

However, when I add a new element `"HELLO"` to my vector, it should return `"NOT UNIQUE"`.

I already tried a bunch of things, but I am not really getting anywhere.

I think a 2 dimensional vector would be a possible solution, but I have not been able to make it work:

```
["DELETE", "D"]
["DELETE", "DE"]
["DELETE", "DEL"]
["DELETE", "DELE"]
["DELETE", "DELET"]
["DELETE", "DELETE"]
["HELP", "HELP"]
["HELLO", "HELL"]
["HELLO", "HELLO"]
...
```

Comment: [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might help.

Comment: should it also result in `GO FORWARD` when input is `F` ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't :)

Comment: You might want to clarify if you want a unique (unambiguous) match of a prefix, maybe give another example input, e.g. "HELL"?

Comment: @Programwizard The accepeted answer answers a different question than what you originally asked. You could have asked a separate question describing accurately(by giving more examples etc) what you actually want. Please don't waste people's time and effort by asking a question and then accpeting the answer that meets the criteria that you did not describe in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Make a function that autodetects when unique

One possible way of doing this is as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::string checkUnique(const std::string& searchString, const std::vector<std::string>& inputVector)
{
    int count = 0;
    std::string foundString;
    for(const std::string &element: inputVector)
    {
        if(element.at(0) == searchString.at(0))
        {
            foundString = element;
            ++count; //increment count
        }
    }
    if(count == 0)
    {
        return "NOT FOUND";
    }
    else if(count == 1)
    {
        return foundString;
    }
    else 
    {
        return "NOT UNIQUE";
    }
}
int main()
{
  
    std::vector<std::string> inputVector{"DELETE", "HELP", "GO FORWARD", "GO BACKWARDS"};
    
    std::string searchString = "H";
    
    //call the function for different cases 
    
    std::cout << checkUnique(searchString, inputVector) <<std::endl;;//prints HELP
    
    std::cout << checkUnique("H", inputVector) << std::endl;  //prints HELP
    
    std::cout << checkUnique("H 55", inputVector) << std::endl; //prints HELP 
    
    //add "HELLO" into the vector 
    inputVector.push_back("HELLO");
    
    std::cout << checkUnique("H", inputVector) << std::endl;  //prints NOT UNIQUE 

    std::cout << checkUnique("H 55", inputVector) << std::endl;  //prints NOT UNIQUE
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/sj0nEYt2A).

Comment: why `rfind` rather than `find` ? I don't think it makes any difference

Comment: you are only checking first characters of input and elements in `inputVector`. Actually you could do the same without any find, but simply `if (element[0] == searchString[0])` would achieve the same

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @AnoopRana oh wait, there is still a problemen. When "HELLO" is added, the algorithm does say that the searchString "HELL" is not unique, but it is. :/

Comment: @Programwizard This is what you desired right? In your question your wrote: **However, when I add a new element "HELLO" to my vector, it should return "NOT UNIQUE".** . So after adding(using push_back) `"HELLO"` there are 2 strings(which are `"HELP"` and `"HELLO"`) inside the `vector` that start with the character `H` and therefore it prints `NOT UNIQUE` as you described in your original question.

Comment: I think it's supposed to find the longest common prefix and bail if that isn't unique, not count matches on first letter.

Comment: @AnoopRana yes, I mean what Hasturkun says. I'm sorry to not fully describe my question.

Comment: @Programwizard I have given the answer according to your original question. If you want a different answer then describe your question properly so that other people don't waste their time. Also, my answer might give you a general idea of how you can do what you want. You can modify the example(answer) given by me according to your needs. Finally, i suggest that you should ask a different(separate) question for a separate purpose. My answer answered your original question which has a separate purpose to what you're telling now. Don't add more requirements later to your original question.

Comment: @AnoopRana: The requirement was there to begin with but was somewhat unclear. This could be inferred from the 2 dimensional vector of prefixes in the question.

Comment: @Hasturkun Nothing can be inferred from the 2D `vector`(at least not to me). I don't give answers based on some guess. I give answer based on what is actually described and asked by the OP. The original question has a completely different purpose to what now OP is asking.

Comment: I did not downvote and I am sorry to ask my question in an unclear way. I will make a new question and put this accept this answer, because your solution does indeed what my OP question says it should do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Programwizard Glad you understood my point.

Answer (score 0):

With a (custom) [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), you might do something like:

```cpp
class Node
{
public:
    std::map<char, Node> children; // Might be a std::array<std::unique_ptr<Node>, 26>
    bool end_of_word = false;
    std::size_t count = 0; // number of words from that point

    Node() = default;

    const Node* get(char c) const
    {
        auto it = children.find(c);

        if (it == children.end()) {
            return nullptr;   
        }
        return &it->second;
    }
};

class Trie
{
    Node root;
public:
 
    void add(const std::string& word)
    {
        Node* node = &root;
        for (const char c : word) {
            node->count++;
            node = &node->children[c];
        }
        node->count++;
        node->end_of_word = true;
    }

    bool contains(const std::string& word) const
    {
        const Node* node = &root;
        for (const auto& c : word) {
            node = node->get(c);
            if (node == nullptr) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return node->end_of_word;
    }
    
    std::optional<std::string> word_from_prefix(const std::string& s)
    {
        std::string res;
        const Node* node = &root;
        for (const auto& c : s) {
            auto next = node->get(c);
            if (next == nullptr) {
                break;
            }
            res += c;
            node = next;
        }
        if (node->count != 1) return std::nullopt;
        while (!node->end_of_word) {
            auto& [c, next] = *node->children.begin();
            res += c;
            node = &next;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d928ddf89a641c0)